# load pdf from redux store

Tags: reactjs, pdf, react-redux

I am trying to download a server side generated pdf file in client, which i get with axios and save it in redux and using FileSaver to download it.

```
const getTicketPdf = ({ userID, ticketID }) =>
    requestApi(`/users/${userID}/tickets/${ticketID}/pdf`, {
        method: 'get',
    });
```

requestApi gets me all neccessary headers so that i can download the file.

the data is then stored in redux like this:

```
data: "%PDF-1.4\n3 0 obj\n<</Type /Page\n/Parent 1 0 R\n/MediaBox [0 0 595.00 842.00]\n/Resources 2 0 R\n/Contents 4 0 R>>\nendobj\n4 0 obj\n<</Filter /FlateDecode /Length 64>>\nstream\nx�3R��2�35W(�*T0P�R0T(\u0007�Y@�\u000e��@Q…"
```

i call it in render with:

```
  <div>
        <button onClick={ () => this.getPdf(ticket) }>PDF</button>
    </div>

getPdf = ticket => {
    const blob = new Blob([ticket]);
    FileSaver.saveAs(blob, 'Ticket.pdf');
}
```

I am always getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'saveAs' of undefined

i tried also to set

> responseType: 'blob'

but this doesn't help either.

Next thing I testet was with react-pdf library, where I managed to display pdf in Component, but i cant print it. User should only habe to save it and then print it locally (or at least show it in separate tab as PDF, which i tried with window.open() as base64 encoded string).

How can I download a server side generated PDF otherwise? Are there any better ways?

Unfortunately I have to set HTTP Headers in order to get that file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You definitely shouldn't save a binary file such as a PDF as a string in your Redux store! Use `Blob`s instead.

Comment: @AKX Saving the data as Blob results in the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error stems from the fact that there is no `FileSaver` object (or rather, it's non-standard).

It seems to be polyfilled by this third-party library: https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js

Comment: Thanks! 
the reason was i destructered the import like:
import { FileSaver } from 'file-saver';

but this works: 

import FileSaver from 'file-saver';

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing is caused by a reference to an undefined variable `FileSaver` - I guess that you are using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/), and need to fix the import. You should also bear in mind that FileSaver is deprecated in favour of the `download` attribute. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29339233/2088135) for details on how to use it.

Either way, in the interests of keeping your store light, you should save a *reference* to the PDF in your Redux store, rather than the string itself.